# Use in the breadcrumb article tag

Tags: html, html5

I'm using the breadcrumb inside the article tag, would that be a good use?

let me give an example

```
<article>
<nav aria-label="Breadcrumb">
<ol>
<li><a href="/">Home Page</a></li>
<li><a href="/category">Cat</a></li>
<li aria-current="page">Post Page</li>
</ol>
</nav>
</article>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not put `<nav>` inside of `<article>`. If your breadcrumbs are applied to ~/blog/*, then they are structural component of your pages, they're not consumable content. For the most part, I'd only put the actual content being consumed in `<article>`.

To my knowledge this would be a proper example, if there's a newer more proper way, someone will clear it up in the comments.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example Post</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <nav>
        <!--Primary Navigation-->
    </nav>
    <header>
        <!--If you have one-->
    </header>
    <nav>
        <ol>
            <li>
                <a href="http://www.example.com/blog">Blog</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="http://www.example.com/blog/category/">Category</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                Example Post
            </li>
        </ol>
    <nav>
    <article>
    <!--article content-->
    </article>
    </body>
</html>
```

I would also recommend combining this with JSON-LD structured data:

*Based on [Googles breadcrumb structured data documentation](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/breadcrumb)*

```html
<head>
    <title>Example Post</title>
        <script type="application/ld+json">
            {
            "@context": "https://schema.org",
            "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
            "itemListElement": [{
                "@type": "ListItem",
                "position": 1,
                "name": "Blog",
                "item": "https://example.com/blog"
            },{
                "@type": "ListItem",
                "position": 2,
                "name": "Science Fiction",
                "item": "https://example.com/blog/category"
            },{
                "@type": "ListItem",
                "position": 3,
                "name": "Example Post"
            }]
            }
        </script>
</head>
```